# Get id of element for JavaScript in MVC4/Razor from nested object in model

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If I define a textbox like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact.HomePhone)
```

it will generate an `input` element with `id` `Contact_HomePhone`.

Is it possible to get this `id` in JavaScript without hardcoding `Contact_HomePhone`?

This is an example of where I need this `id` dynamically in JavaScript:

```
$("#Contact_HomePhone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

(I know how to get property names using reflection, but would still have to hardcode `_` to concatenate `Contact` and `HomePhone`.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this way, using  **[Html.IdFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833709(v=vs.108).aspx)** you can get the id generated by the helper.

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Contact.HomePhone)').mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

Just prefix it with `#` for jquery to pick it up.

But you can also bind the plugin using class selector, say for example if you have many such phone fields you can provide a common class to all those textBoxes and bind mask plugin to it using the class selector, this would avoid determining the id using the above method and use a common selector.

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Contact.HomePhone, null, new { @class = "phoneField"});
```

and without worrying about the id you can just bind them.

```
 $('.phoneField').mask("(999) 999-9999");
```